# Smarty : translate "date|niceTime" result

Tags: smarty

I use smart and i use this code now , and it works as well as possible ..

```
date|niceTime
```

but the problem that i want translate this code results .. 
outpot example : 5 days ago 
outpot example after translation : depuis 5 jours

Comment: `niceTime` doesn't appear in [the list of built-in modifiers](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers), so presumably it's either something written for your application, or downloaded from somewhere else. Finding how to translate it will depend on finding what function you're actually running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate this modifier: [Smarty date modifier plugin](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=61841)

```
'Sekunde', 'Sekunden',    // 1,1 
'Minute','Minuten',      // 3,3 
'Stunde', 'Stunden',   // 5,5 
'Tag', 'Tagen',         // 7,7 
'Woche', 'Wochen',      // 9,9 
'Monat', 'Monaten',      // 11,12 
'Jahr','Jahren');      // 13,14
```

Example:

```
{$date|timeAgo}
```